# Use funnel approcah is SQL to see bailout at each level

Tags: sql

I want to do funnel approach to see participation of customers. Question I want to answer is “Do people do few first run actions before they start playing the game app”,  “How many people I started with and I am losing at every step”,  “How many people eventually started playing the game”. I want the data to be grouped by each application also called TID.  I am super confused on how to do it. Any help would be really helpful. I am using MS SQL.

I want the above answers in conjunction with 
 - how many people completed some series of action over multiple
   sessions and eventually
 - how many people completed some series of action in a single session.

a.  Session is field SessionId, UserID is field CID, TID represents app. (I am getting data from multiple games doing similar things)
b.  Actions has basically some actions that user has to do, before he starts using the application. He can’t start using the application before he does some actions.
 1. The actions are always more than 1 (2 or 3)
 2. The actions could be different on different form factors tablet/phablet/phone.
 3. The actions have _ to identify the sequence.
 4. The actions could be different on left to right or right to left UI.
 5. The actions could be different on different languages.
 6. Here are some sample sequence in which user will see the actions.
    a.  Branding_tablet_1 -- Branding_tablet_2 -- “Play Game Now”
    b.  Jewels_tablet_1 -- Jewels_tablet_2 -- “Play Game Now"
    c.  Branding_RTL_tablet_1 -- Branding_RTL_tablet_2 -- “استخدم التطبيق
    الآن”

7. There could be bail outs, i.e. people finish action _1, but get bored, but the app in background and never come to do action _2 and never “Play Game Now”
8. There could be another set of actions which do not have a _1 or _2 associated with them, but we can know when they were triggered using timestamp. (timestamp is also available for 3 to 7 above). Here is an example
   a.  Hunter_Amazon_LTR_Phone -- Hunter_Equator_LTR_Phone -- “Play Game Now” but it only happens when TID is 12
9. There could be case when  but it only happens when TID is 27. In this case, there is only 1 action. I WANT TO IGNORE IT. I only want to collect data when I have action1, action2 and the “Play game now”
   a.  Soldier  “Play Game Now”
10. The action information and “Play Game Now” live in separate tables but field name is same ‘Action”. _1 and _2 are in UserAction table but “Play Game Now” is in a separate table called "Play" table.

    ```
    SELECT [SessionId]
      ,[TID]
      ,[CollectionTime]
      ,[Action]
      ,[CID]
    FROM [CXE].[dbo].[UserAction]

    SELECT [SessionId]
      ,[CollectionTime]
      ,[Action]
      ,[CID]
      ,[TID]
    FROM [CXE].[dbo].[Play]
    ```

I would want an output in this form:

```
    Action         TID    Count  
    1               1     2003  
    2               1     1751  
    'PlayGameNow'   1     1489  
    1               2     1763  
    2               2     1541  
  'PlayGameNow'     2     1236  
    1               3     2959    
    2               3     1751  
  'PlayGameNow'     3     1640  
    1               4     2278  
    2               4     1765  
  'PlayGameNow'     4     1489
```

Comment: How action has string and numbers? try this to format a table http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: You didnt include the sample data.

Comment: @Juan Here is the link to sample data. I uploaded it in Google drive since the other tool was not able to handle the data. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1jtJO7sGlA0VjI2QllvNGdWT3M&usp=sharing